# where to use MYSQL query caching

Tags: mysql, caching

## problem

My question is I am developing a system. I click a query caching concept for fast response time. now I want to find which kind of traffic on system on web application is better for query caching and which is not. and what is the downside of query caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Whether Query Cache is good for you? Depends on

- what MySQL version are you using
- what is the scale of your application
- what kind of queries you want to cache

#### How it works

If MySQL Query Cache is used, MySQL won't go to the trouble of **parsing** the query every time the query is hit. MySQL will look for a identical query in the **query cache** whenever a query is hit and if it finds the query, it won't need to parse it again, it will just send it to the server and fetch the results.

#### Issues & Limitations

Please do remember that the cache doesn't store data of your query. You will not receive old/stale data from a cached query. **It just stores the parsed query.** But a point to be made here is that if the underlying tables (of the cached query) undergo any change, all the tables being used in the cache will be invalidated.

Among other things, there are serious limitations to the Query Cache. Cached queries cannot be used for stored procedures, functions and triggers. They're also not used for queries which are subqueries of an outer query.

It was once considered a great tool for speeding up the queries, but recently MySQL development team has decided to retire this feature as they found some scalability issues with the query cache.

Do read this [this article on MySQL Server Team's blog about retiring the Query Cache in MySQL 8.0](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-retiring-support-for-the-query-cache/)